# Add new IdentityRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to add a new role to the ASP.NET Core Identity system.
But no luck so far.

**Code: C#**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

private ApplicationDbContext _context;

var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_context);
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore); // <============ Problem
await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Somevalue"));
```

**Error message:**

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'roleValidators' of 'RoleManager.RoleManager(IRoleStore, IEnumerable>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, ILogger>, IHttpContextAccessor)'

**Same code in .net 4.6 VB.net works**

```
    Dim roleManager = New RoleManager(Of IdentityRole)(New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole))
    Dim newRoleName As String = "Some groupname"

    If Not roleManager.RoleExists(newRoleName) Then

        Dim role = New IdentityRole()

        role.Name = newRoleName
        roleManager.Create(role)

    End If
```

Comment: Could you post your `Startup.cs` code related aspnet identity?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you try to use aspnet identity without dependency injection. See [official docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html) how to configure identity with aspnet core.